# How to create a function that takes a character and string and returns the index of this character in the string

Tags: java, arrays

i'm trying to solve the hangman game exercise .
the hangman game is randomly generates a word and
prompts the user to guess one letter at a time. Each
letter in the word is displayed as an asterisk. When the user makes a correct
guess, the actual letter is then displayed. When the user finishes a word, display 
the number of misses and ask the user whether to continue to play with another
word.
everything was good till i have an bug this bug is when i run the program 
if the word that pecked is such (overflow) the first 'O' in the word appear but the second 'O' doesn't 'cause the program can't Differentiates between both.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  char again = 'y' ;
  int missed = 0;
  String[] words = {"computer" , "programming" , "web" , "android"};

  do{

  String word = words[(int)(Math.random()*4)];

  int size = word.length();

  char[] asterisk = new char[size];

  for(int i=0; i<size; i++){

      asterisk[i] = '*';

  }

      do{
      System.out.print("(Guess) Enter a letter in word ");

      for(int i=0; i<asterisk.length; i++) System.out.print(asterisk[i]);

      char guess = input.next().charAt(0);

      for(int i=0; i<asterisk.length; i++){

          if(guess==(char)word.charAt(i)){

              int Index_of_guess=where(guess,word);

              asterisk[Index_of_guess]=guess;
          }
          else missed++;
      }}while(check(asterisk));

      System.out.print("The word is ");
      for(int i=0; i<asterisk.length; i++) System.out.print(asterisk[i]);
      System.out.println(" You missed " + missed + " time");
      if(missed>1)
          System.out.print("s");

      System.out.println("Do you want to guess another word? Enter y or n > ");
      again = input.next().charAt(0);


  }while(again=='y');
}

public static boolean check(char[] asterisk){
    for(int i=0; i<asterisk.length; i++){
        if(asterisk[i]=='*')
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public static int where(char guess, String word){
    for(int i=0; i<word.length(); i++){
        if(guess== word.charAt(i))
            return i;
            }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `public static int where(char guess, String word) { return word.indexOf(guess); }`

Comment: If your `where` method returns 0, is that because the word starts with the character, or is it because the character wasn't found? Hmmm.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `where()` method is completely unnecessary and the reason your program isn't working, since it's returning the index of the first occurrence of the character. Simply replace

```
if(guess == (char) word.charAt(i)) {
    int Index_of_guess = where(guess,word);
    asterisk[Index_of_guess] = guess;
}
```

with

```
if(guess == (char) word.charAt(i)) {
    asterisk[i] = guess;
}
```